# Resizing and icon on a jpanel with card layout

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create an application where a list of numbers are listed on the `WEST` region of `BorderLayout` and corresponding panels in the `CENTER`. The problem is that

- I need the `WEST` region to be wider. Right now, it contains `JList` in a `JPanel` which resizes it to its default size. Preferred size? Not sure!
- I need to have an icon or alphabet character 'x' towards the right end of 1 or 2. So, that when I close it, I can close the corresponding panel on the CENTER.

CODE:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Sample1 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Sample1 frame = new Sample1();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Sample1() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        Vector<String> str = new Vector<>();
        str.add("1");
        str.add("2");
        final JList list = new JList();
        list.setListData(str);
        panel.add(list);

        final JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel_1.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panel_2 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.add(panel_2, "1");

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("First");
        panel_2.add(lblNewLabel);

        JPanel panel_3 = new JPanel();
        panel_1.add(panel_3, "2");

        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Second");
        panel_3.add(lblNewLabel_1);


        list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) panel_1.getLayout();
                layout.show(panel_1, list.getSelectedValue().toString());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a JTable with two columns. The second column can contain a close button. See [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=table%20button%20column) for an example of this approach.

Otherwise you would need to add a panel to the WEST. The panel would contain the JList and some other component beside the JList to act as the close button. The problem with this approach is getting the components to line up and for the button to know which panel to close.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout` also try setting up your GUI with a separate methods.

Setup GUI Code:

```
private void setupGUI() {
        JPanel westP = setupWestPane();

        getContentPane().add(westPa, BorderLayout.WEST);          
    }
```

Setup West Pane Code:

```
private JPanel setupWestPane() {
    JPanel westP = setupWestPanel();


    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 20, 0));
    p.setOpaque(false);
    p.add(westP);
    return p;
}
```

Setup West Panel Code :

```
private JPanel setupPlayerPanel() {
        list1 = new JList();
        list1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        // If you want to add a listener to the listbox
        // list1.addListSelectionListener(this);
        JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(playerList);

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.setOpaque(false);
        p.add(new JLabel("List"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        p.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return p;
    }
```

The code above is just an example.